# intellij doesnt compile some classes that are in the source folder

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I tried to use some methods in a class. When I tried to use them it can't find the class in the source folder. [the source folder and the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaH0w.png)

[image: example of the files]

The class is right there in the source folder, and the line and point classes can be used just fine. Why won't GUI and `DrawSurface` work?

I also tried it like this: [the classes in a folder and I import them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxJ5A.png)
like you can see there are a lot of classes in there, but when I want to import one of them it doesn't work.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/specifying-compilation-settings.html

Comment: thank you very much for the link but i am really new to java programming,am i supposed to add the classes to the list?

Comment: Do you have a package or a default package? Move the java files to a package

Comment: What the red bulb suggest?
Are your classes public?

Comment: Also set the working directory to the folder that contains the working directory(root folder). To fix this, go to "Run" > "Edit Configurations...", and add on to the field titled "Working Directory.

Comment: yes the classes are public,. the working directory was in the right spot.i moved the java files to the biuoop package which include more classes and did import(i edited the main comment),but still doesn't work .thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should choose JDK

> File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project SDK

Answer (score 0):

Why do you keep compiled classes in sources folder? Move them to separate folder and add it as dependency in "Project Structure | Modules | Dependencies"

Comment: IDE doesn't look into .class files if they are not added as a dependency. It searches through sources and dependencies for classes/methods.  If they are not there IDE marks them as unresolved.